Are there any sets that are not constructible?
I am new to set theory.
As I understand it, complex sets are constructed by set constructors from simpler sets (originally atoms).
I learned that such a set is called a constructible set.
I do not know of any set that is not constructible. Are there any examples?

The answer to this question depends on exactly what axioms of set theory one starts from (and the exact definition of "constructible"). In some formulations of set theory, every set is constructible; in other formulations, the second sentence is not true.

Relevant: Constructible universe.

Compare with this post and others here.

@GregMartin Do you have a concrete example of which set is not constructible in which formulation?

Set of uncomputable numbers

@jimjim I do not know the exact definition of computability, but if it can be written in the language of set theory, then the set can be constructed by the axiom schema of specification.

The term doesn't mean what you seem to expect it to mean. In particular, you can't prove that the set of real numbers, or complex numbers, etc. is constructible in the technical meaning of the word in set theory. Moreover, the two tags you're using should, in theory, be disjoint.
